# What is the mysterious "TL;DR" that appears at the top of many Questions and Answers?

Tags: discussion, support

## TL;DR

The above is an example.  I put it there intentionally.  I see it at the top of a lot of Q's and A's on Main.  What is it? Why is it there?  Is it kbd shrtcut emoji kewl speak I just don't understand 'cause I'm older than 21?  Or is it some indication of incompatible Markdown editors being used which generates interesting stray characters like that?  Or is it something far more sinister, like Skynet flexing its muscles?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[TL; DR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TL;DR) - Too long; Didn't read.

---

I probably couldn't phrase it better than @T.E.D. did in the comments:

> Its basically Millennial for "The executive summary is..."

Comment: Ah.  Ok.  Thanks... but then why would an OP put it at the top of their own Q?  I checked the Edit history - no one added it later it was in the original version.  Guess I still don't get it.

Comment: @KerryL I reckon it's just the equivalent of a precis at the start of an essay.

Comment: btw I have spent several days musing over something else that has been equally perplexing me... feel free to leave me perplexed.  Is it "sempai scuba," "sempai's Cuba," "sempa is Cuba," none of the above (?) :-)

Comment: Its basically Millineal for "The executive summary is..."

Comment: @KerryL Sempai SCUBA (I'm also a diving instructor with the British Sub-Aqua Club). ;-)

Comment: @KerryL I put TL;DR at the top of my questions for anyone who doesn't have the time to read a long question and just needs to know my key points; it's popular on a lot of forums, and I just see it as being mindful.

Comment: @sempaiscuba - I've always read it as *semper, I scuba* ;-)

Comment: @TheHonRose SemperSCUBA would work too! ;-)